# Which process/library transform backspace into ansi escape sequence, like "\33[nG", in linux(ubuntu) application?

Tags: linux, windows, ansi-escape

I have writen a command line application (called "**App-CLI**" below) running on **linux**.  App-CLI works as a server, and after accepting a connection, it will fork a child process as a working process and allocate a pty (via openpty function) in each such child process. In each child process, I use a editline library, like libedit, to deal with the user input.

Then, in situation 1:

I use tools like cmd/ConEmu/git bash in **Win10** to connect APP-CLI via telnet or SSH, and I enter some characters, eg, "abcdefg", excluding the double quotes. And then, I enter the **backspace** key, the screen in the cmd tool shows `"[K"` at the start of the origin line. So I use strate in Linux to spy what App-CLI outputs

`strace -e write=1,2 -e trate=write, -p {process_id}`

and gets result likes

`write(1, "\r\33[6G\33[K", 8)         = 8`

which is composed of **CSI sequenses**:

- CSI n G, named "Cursor Horizontal Absolute" (CHA), it means "Moves the cursor to column n (default 1). (not ANSI.SYS)" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) .
- CSI n K, named "Erase in Line", it means "Erases part of the line. If n is 0 (or missing), clear from cursor to the end of the line. If n is 1, clear from cursor to beginning of the line. If n is 2, clear entire line. Cursor position does not change".

It seems that cmd or win10 cannot successfully handle CHA sequence ? But I cannot find information concerned informing the (non)supportability.

And then, in situation 2:

I still use cmd tool in win10. But I first log in the linux system by telnet, and then connect to the APP-CLI via telnet in linux. I enter "abcdefg" and **backspace** key likewise, and this time, all things go right: The output on the screen shows "abcdef". The monitor data under strace is :

`write(1, "\10\33[K", 4)         = 4`

The sequence represting the backspace key changed! So I want to know :

1. Such sequences are generated by which process or library in linux ?
2. Whether I can decide which kind of sequence to be finally generate , and how I can ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Such sequences are generated by which process or library in linux ?

In your case I think the sequences are generated by what you called *a editline library*. Naturally, functions which control the appearance of the terminal input line use control sequences.

> Whether I can decide which kind of sequence to be finally generate , and how I can ?

Which control sequences are used is determined by the terminal capabilities database and the effective terminal type, usually set by the `TERM` variable (it may be that certain libraries allow configuration of the terminal type in other ways). You could check whether `$TERM` is different in the two scenarios you described.

Comment: Yeap, the terminal type in the former is "ansi", and latter is "xterm-256-color". I have read the code in the libedit, where just use the common io function like printf/flush. I just wonder whether i can choose the kind of sequnces out of terminal type.

Comment: libedit seems to use libcurses, so you should be able to choose this by setting the proper terminal type prior to invoking a function of libedit, perhaps by calling `putenv("TERM=…")`; a good implementation of `telnet` would pass this automatically, but your cmd/ConEmu/git bash seem not to do it. Anyway, the right terminal definition has to be in effect in order for something like libedit to work properly.

Comment: I used the api supported by libedit to set the terminal type before, but it resulted in the problems I listed in the question. And now I use your recommended library function, and cancel the call of libedit api, and finally the problem get solved. Thank you!